# WPF Star ColumnDefinition doesn't work as it should

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to generate a raport that must be on multiple pages using wpf.
I have readen from https://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/wpf-printing-part-2-the-fixed-document.aspx how to do it, and I am trying to recreate my wpf page dynamically.

This is the XAML I am trying to recreate:

```
<Grid Name="printRaport">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" Name="menuRowDefinition"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="White"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Name="dataRaportPDF" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Data: " FontSize="17" Margin="10 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="filtruRaportPDF" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Filtru: " FontSize="17" Margin="10 0"/>
                </Grid>


                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="RAPORT Cantariri" FontSize="23" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="perioadaRaportPDF" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Perioada: " FontSize="17"/>
                </Grid>

                <TextBlock Name="netRaportPDF" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Total NET: " FontSize="20" Margin="20 0" FontWeight="Bold"/>

            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <ListView Name="raportDataGridPDF" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding tichete}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding operatie}" Header="Operatie" Width="75"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nr}" Header="Nr" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding data}" Header="Data" Width="130"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding vehicul}" Header="Vehicul" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding furnizor}" Header="Furnizor" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding client}" Header="Client" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding produs}" Header="Produs" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding brut}" Header="Brut" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding tara}" Header="Tara" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding net}" Header="Net" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding depozit}" Header="Depozit" Width="75"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding observatii}" Header="Observatii" Width="210"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

I tried to recreate it like this (the function I show you is the one without any functions, I tried even recreating it step by step, class by class so any problems won't show throughout methods)

```
private void printareRaportButton2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() != true) return;

            FixedDocument fixedDocument = new FixedDocument();
            fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new System.Windows.Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);

            // Set up pagination variables
            int itemsPerPage = 10;
            int currentPage = 0;
            int totalItems = tichete.Count;
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalItems / itemsPerPage);

            // Print each page
            while (currentPage < totalPages)
            {
                FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
                fixedPage.Width = fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
                fixedPage.Height = fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

                //PrintVisual(raportPDFWindow.printRaport, fixedPage, currentPage, itemsPerPage);
                Grid grid = new Grid();
                grid.Name = "printRaport";

                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

                Border border = new Border();
                border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
                border.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;

                Grid grid2 = new Grid();
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                }

                // First Grid within the main Grid
                Grid firstInnerGrid = new Grid();
                firstInnerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                firstInnerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

                TextBlock dataRaportPDF = new TextBlock() { Name = "dataRaportPDF", VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, Text = "Data: ", FontSize = 17, Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0) };
                TextBlock filtruRaportPDF = new TextBlock() { Name = "filtruRaportPDF", VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, Text = "Filtru: ", FontSize = 17, Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0) };
                filtruRaportPDF.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);

                Grid.SetRow(dataRaportPDF, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(filtruRaportPDF, 1);

                firstInnerGrid.Children.Add(dataRaportPDF);
                firstInnerGrid.Children.Add(filtruRaportPDF);

                // Second Grid within the main Grid
                Grid secondInnerGrid = new Grid();
                secondInnerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                secondInnerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

                TextBlock raportTitle = new TextBlock() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, Text = "RAPORT Cantariri", FontSize = 23, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold };
                TextBlock perioadaRaportPDF = new TextBlock() { Name = "perioadaRaportPDF", VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, Text = "Perioada: ", FontSize = 17 };
                perioadaRaportPDF.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);


                secondInnerGrid.Children.Add(raportTitle);
                secondInnerGrid.Children.Add(perioadaRaportPDF);

                // Third TextBlock within the main Grid
                TextBlock netRaportPDF = new TextBlock() { Name = "netRaportPDF", VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right, Text = "Total NET: ", FontSize = 20, Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0), FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold };
                netRaportPDF.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);

                // Add inner Grids and TextBlock to the main Grid
                grid2.Children.Add(firstInnerGrid);
                grid2.Children.Add(secondInnerGrid);
                grid2.Children.Add(netRaportPDF);

                // Set Grid positions within the main Grid
                Grid.SetColumn(firstInnerGrid, 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(secondInnerGrid, 1);

                // Add the main Grid to the Border
                border.Child = grid2;


                grid.Children.Add(border);

                fixedPage.Children.Add(grid);

                PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
                ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
                fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent);

                currentPage++;
            }
            printDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "Invoice");
        }
```

I simply cannot understand why my columnDefinitions doesn't work on star (I tried on pixels, it worked). The result looks like this:

(See figure)

Any idea why..? I really want to understand

I was expecting to get the wpf window I obtained from my xaml file, but it seems like all that I get is that figure I printed...